# Changing the Heat transfer model of the ClosedVolume of the Modelica Standard Library lead to an unbalanced model

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

The documentation of the `Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume` says that `IdealHeatTransfer` is considered by default. I'd like to use `ConstantFlowHeatTransfer` instead. I declare it in the Text View. However, doing so leads to an unbalanced model : 939 equations and 943 variables.

Here is the model :

[image]

And here is the code used :

```
model Closed_volume_test

replaceable package Medium=Modelica.Media.Water.ConstantPropertyLiquidWater constrainedby Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium;

replaceable model HeatTransfer_1 = Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.HeatTransfer.ConstantFlowHeatTransfer(alpha0=1800);

replaceable model HeatTransfer_2 = Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.HeatTransfer.ConstantFlowHeatTransfer(alpha0=8000);


  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume(redeclare package Medium = Medium, redeclare final model HeatTransfer = HeatTransfer_1, V = 20, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyState, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyState, nPorts= 2, use_HeatTransfer = true,  use_portsData = false)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, -36}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 0.15, length = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {26, -54}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T boundary1(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = 328.15, m_flow = 1,nPorts = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-56, -54}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary(redeclare package Medium = Medium,T = 328.15, nPorts = 1, p = 1e5)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {56, -54}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-88, 32}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe1(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 0.15, length = 1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-26, -54}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe2(redeclare package Medium = Medium, redeclare final model HeatTransfer = HeatTransfer_2, diameter = 38e-3, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyState, length = 15, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyState, momentumDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyState, nNodes = 10, use_HeatTransfer = true)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 28}, extent = {{-10, 10}, {10, -10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary2(redeclare package Medium = Medium,T = 311.15, nPorts = 1, p = 14.6e5)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-36, 28}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T boundary3(redeclare package Medium = Medium,m_flow = -0.25, nPorts = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {36, 28}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatExchanger.BaseClasses.WallConstProps wallConstProps(area_h = 0.89, c_wall = 510, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyState, k_wall = 60.5, n = 10, rho_wall = 7850, s = 3e-3)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 8}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.ThermalCollector thermalCollector(m = 10)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, -10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

equation
  connect(boundary1.ports[1], pipe1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-46, -54}, {-36, -54}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe.port_b, boundary.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{36, -54}, {46, -54}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(volume.ports[1], pipe1.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, -46}, {-16, -46}, {-16, -54}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(volume.ports[2], pipe.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, -46}, {16, -46}, {16, -54}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(boundary2.ports[1], pipe2.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-26, 28}, {-10, 28}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe2.port_b, boundary3.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{10, 28}, {26, 28}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe2.heatPorts, wallConstProps.heatPort_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, 24}, {0, 13}}, color = {127, 0, 0}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(wallConstProps.heatPort_b, thermalCollector.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, 3}, {0, 0}}, color = {191, 0, 0}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(thermalCollector.port_b, volume.heatPort) annotation(
    Line(points = {{0, -20}, {-10, -20}, {-10, -36}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));

end Closed_volume_test;
```

Is it possible to use another model for the heat transfer for the ClosedVolume ? If so, does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Best regards
Maxime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConstantFlowHeatTransfer` is inherited from `PartialFlowHeatTransfer` which uses quantities such as `length` and `nParallel` which are not defined (and have no meaning) in the volume model. This is why you cannot use it.

`ClosedVolume` uses heat transfer models that inherit from `PartialVesselHeatTransfer`. You can build your own heat transfer model based on this.

If you need to consider the convective heat transfer in the "lower" medium of your model you could replace `pipe`, `pipe1` and `volume` with a `DynamicPipe` model (with `modelStructure=a_v_b` and `nNodes=1`).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I don't really understand modelStructure and their impacts on the results, do you know where I could find information besides the ones in `Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.PartialTwoPortFlow`, results on the web are not really helpful

Comment: `modelStructure=a_v_b` denotes "port_a — flow model — volume model — flow model — port_b", just like you have used two `StaticPipe` (flow models) and one `ClosedVolume` 
 (volume model) models. It is described in the paper "Standardization of Thermo-Fluid Modeling in Modelica.Fluid"